# jOOQ 3.1 prints logs, but jOOQ 3.4 doesn't

Tags: spring, tomcat, log4j, jooq

I'm having a strange problem in my project (Spring, log4j, maven, jOOQ). The project is a multi-jar with a parent and a common poms shared by all the children projects.

**The problem**

If I use jOOQ **3.1** in one of the child projects, the rolling file is created and updated with all the logs. If I recompile the project using jOOQ **3.4** (jar is a dependency of the common pom project) my rolling file is not created and I don't get any logs.

Why did I upgrade from 3.1 to 3.4? Because I was getting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395359/jooq-spring-and-bonecp-connection-closed-twice-error).

My **log4j.properties** file is as follows:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout, rollingFile

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t %c] - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%c{3}] %m%n

log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=${catalina.base}/logs/my_file.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%c] - %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.Append=true
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=99
```

I can't think of a relation between the jOOQ version and printing / not printing logs, especially as [the jOOQ documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-execution/logging/) makes clear that it's very easy to log. So that's why I have to ask you guys.

Please don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Thanks everyone!

**UPDATE 1 - Pom sources**

These are all the concerned poms (some details have been modified for obvious reasons)

**super_parent_module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my_group_id</groupId>
    <artifactId>super_parent_module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>name</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>XXXXX</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
       <!-- repository -->
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <!-- profiles -->
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <deployment.local.directory>XXXXX</deployment.local.directory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>XXXXXXX</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/generated/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4.2</version>
               <configuration>
                  <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                  <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                  <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
                  <remoteTagging>true</remoteTagging>
                  <tagBase>XXXXXXXX</tagBase>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**super_common_module**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent> 
        <groupId>my_group_id</groupId>  
        <artifactId>super_parent_module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>super_common_module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>name</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>XXXXXX</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- guava 15 -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>args4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>with-deps</shadedClassifierName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

**parent_module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent> 
        <groupId>my_group_id</groupId>  
        <artifactId>super_parent_module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my_group_id.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent_module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>parent_module</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>XXXXXX</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <modules>
        <module>common_module</module>
        <module>my_problematic_module</module>
        <module>other_module</module>
        <module>other_module</module>       
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <!-- profiles -->
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <springws.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</springws.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jooq.version>3.4.0</jooq.version>
        <jooq-codegen.url>XXXXX</jooq-codegen.url>
        <jooq-codegen.user>XXXXX</jooq-codegen.user>
        <jooq-codegen.password>XXXX</jooq-codegen.password>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my_group_id</groupId>
            <artifactId>super_common_module</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**common_module**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent> 
        <groupId>my_group_id.client</groupId>  
        <artifactId>parent_module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>common_module</artifactId>
    <description>description</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>name</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- jOOQ configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>14</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>my_group_id</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jooq-ext</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                        <url>${jooq-codegen.url}</url>
                        <user>${jooq-codegen.user}</user>
                        <password>${jooq-codegen.password}</password>
                    </jdbc>
                    <generator>
                        <name>org.jooq.util.MyGenerator</name>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase</name>
                            <includes>tables and packages</includes>
                            <excludes />
                            <inputSchema>my_schema</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <generate>
                            <relations>true</relations>
                            <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                            <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
                            <generatedAnnotation>false</generatedAnnotation>
                            <records>true</records>
                            <pojos>false</pojos>
                            <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
                            <interfaces>false</interfaces>
                            <daos>false</daos>
                            <jpaAnnotations>false</jpaAnnotations>
                            <validationAnnotations>false</validationAnnotations>
                            <globalObjectReferences>false</globalObjectReferences>
                        </generate>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>my_group_id.model.generated</packageName>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-xxxxx/jooq</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**my_problematic_module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my_group_id.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent_module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my_problematic_module</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>name</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <url>http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws</url>

    <profiles>
        <!-- profiles... -->
    </profiles>

    <scm>
        <connection>XXXXXX</connection>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${lane}</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>   
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8084/manager</url>
                    <server>mytomcat</server>
                    <path>/project_path</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exec_id</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>2.0</target>
                            <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>exec_id.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <xjcArgs>
                                <!-- xjcArg>some args</xjcArg -->
                            </xjcArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- another execution -->
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>XXXXX</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/generated/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>common_module</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>XXXXX</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/generated/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your pom.xml(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

I have noticed that jooq-codegen-maven-3.4.0.jar has a log4j.xml and that jooq-codegen-maven-3.1.0.jar doesn't.

I have then created a log4j.xml file to replace my log4j.properties and the rollingFile has started writing again!

I believe log4j was using the xml version in jooq-codegen-maven-3.4.0.jar (which writes in console only) and not my log4j.properties. Maybe there's a way to tell log4j which file has more priority, but apparently creating this other log4j.xml has overriden jooq's.

@LukasEder, do you think this should be taken care of in jooq?

Thanks

Comment: You're right, having added this XML to the Maven plugin was probably a mistake. That should be fixed: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3408

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `log4j` dependency in your pom.xml file. jOOQ tries to find that dependency on the classpath, but you haven't added it (at least not in that module).

Try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

(It's curious that this would have worked prior to jOOQ 3.4)

Comment: Sorry Lukas, the dependencies go higher than I thought. I've refactored all dependencies to avoid repetitions and have added the super_parent_module and super_common_module. You'll see that log4j is in the super_parent_module. When I create the final war, log4j is present under the lib folder

Comment: Hmm, OK. I'm not that good with Maven, I hope someone else will be able to sort it out. Sorry about that...

Comment: Hi Lukas, regarding this problem, I have found a difference between jooq 3.1 and 3.4. In jooq-codegen-maven-3.4.0.jar there's a log4j.xml file and in jooq-codegen-maven-3.1.0.jar that file doesn't exist. Maybe this configuration overrides mine. Can this be a possibility?

Comment: @EduCastrillon: Hmm, nice catch. This was indeed changed in jOOQ 3.2: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2733. Maybe that was a bad idea... [I guess we can revert that](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3408)